# JS Same Object Key

Tags: javascript

I have an object. I want to duplicate object keys. But I've searched for this. They said it is not possible. If there is no way to to this, I want to create new syntax and new file type. Example at the bottom. How can I create a new syntax and file type? But in my file type I have to be able to duplicate object keys. Thank you so much.

```js
{
  // index endpoints
  get: {
    path: '/',
    handler: 'IndexController.homepage'
  },

  // movie endpoints
  group: {
    prefix: '/movies',
    get: {
      path: '/',
      handler: 'MovieController.find'
    },
    post: {
      path: '/',
      handler: 'MovieController.create',
      authenticated: true,
      permissions: {
        moderator: true,
        admin: true
      },
      middleware: ['FileUpload.upload:single,poster']
    }
  },

  // auth endpoints
  group: {
    prefix: '/auth',
    post: {
      path: '/sign-up',
      handler: 'AuthController.signUp'
    },
    post: {
      path: '/sign-in',
      handler: 'AuthController.signIn'
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// index endpoints
get:
  path: '/'
  handler: 'IndexController.homepage'

// movie endpoints
group:
  prefix: '/movies'
  get:
    path: '/'
    handler: 'MovieController.find'
  post:
    path: '/'
    handler: 'MovieController.create'
    permissions:
      moderator: true,
      admin: true
    middleware: ['FileUpload.upload:single,poster']

// auth endpoints
group:
  prefix: '/auth',
  post:
    path: '/sign-up'
    handler: 'AuthController.signUp'
  post:
    path: '/sign-in'
    handler: 'AuthController.signIn'
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to have identical key. You could put the objects in a JSON array. Where each key-value is an individual object.

```
[{},{},{}]
```

For your example, it will be:

```
endpoints: [
   {
   group:
     prefix: '/movies'
     get:
       path: '/'
       handler: 'MovieController.find'
     post:
       path: '/'
       handler: 'MovieController.create'
       permissions:
         moderator: true,
         admin: true
       middleware: ['FileUpload.upload:single,poster']
   }{
   // auth endpoints
   group:
     prefix: '/auth',
     post:
       path: '/sign-up'
       handler: 'AuthController.signUp'
     post:
       path: '/sign-in'
       handler: 'AuthController.signIn'
   }
]
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But if I'd do that, there will be a lot of objects. I don't want that. By the way you've duplicate keys in this example. :)